# Post facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try send comment to group using graph of facebook , and all it´s perfect i put the app id , id of group and other things , in the API put it´s necessary use post for send message

```
  <?php
    $graph="https://graph.facebook.com";
    $id_group="1111111111111111";
    $app_id="234wwwwwwwwwww";
    $token="234wwwwwwwwwww|038bb73d7a0c6599115ea78b16f0095a";
    ?> 

<form action="<?php echo $graph;?>/<?php echo $id_group;?>/feed?app_id=<?php echo $app_id;?>&access_token=<?php echo $token;?>" method="post">
<textarea name="message">Message Test</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
</form>
```

When send post always get this :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

But i have the app authorized in my profile , by this i don´t understand why no works

Regards

Answer (score 0):

i guess your app is missing appropriate permissions from the error message received . please refer to the  [group/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed) documentation .

> **Permissions**
>
> - For an app and game group, a user access token with the
>   publish_actions permission is required to post on behalf of the user.
> - For all other kinds of groups, a user access token with
>   publish_actions and user_groups permission is required for someone
>   able to post to the group.
> - An app can post to an app and game group
>   feed using an app access token which posts as the app.

when you authenticate and obtain access token for the user make sure you do that with both `publish_actions` and `user_groups` permissions .